# My code always throw exception error

Tags: c#

Hi my question is this when i input a value more than 7 it always throw me exception Index was out of range: must be a Non-Negative or less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: Index. Here's my Code

```
List<int> sample = new List<int>();
DataTable dataHolder = new DataTable();
int counter;
int secondCounter;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        sample.Add(rnd.Next(90, 100));
    }
    dataHolder.Columns.Add("Random Number", typeof(string));
    dataHolder.Columns.Add("Average", typeof(string));
    counter = 0;
    secondCounter = 0;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> collectionHOlder = new List<int>();

    for (int a = 0; a < 96; a++)
    {
        //if (a != sample.Count)
            for (int i = a; i <= Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) - 1 + a; i++)
            {
                counter++;
                secondCounter++;
                if (i <= 96)
                {
                    collectionHOlder.Add(sample[i]);

                }

                if (secondCounter < Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    dataHolder.Rows.Add(sample[i].ToString(), "");

                }
                if (counter == Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    dataHolder.Rows.Add(sample[i].ToString(), collectionHOlder.Average());
                }

            }
        counter = 0;
        collectionHOlder.Clear();
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataHolder;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int a = 0; a < 96; a++)
{   
   for (int i = a; i <= Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) - 1 + a; i++)
```

When the input is 7 and a reaches 95, this becomes 7 - 1 + 95 = 101.

Previously,

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
  {
     sample.Add(rnd.Next(90, 100));
  }
```

created an array of 101 elements, valid positions `0..100`.

So yes, `sample[i]` will throw that exception when i >= 101.

---

As a general advice, break this code in smaller steps and use meaningful names. Makes it easier to debug, find and fix errors.

Comment: This code always generate 102 

 if (i <= sample.Count)
                        {
                            collectionHOlder.Add(sample[i]);
                           
                        }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your answer. I finish this problem now this is my solution

```
                **if(i < sample.Count - 1)**
                if (counter == Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text))
                    dataHolder.Rows.Add(sample[i].ToString(), collectionHOlder.Average());
```